# Visual studio 2010 installer issue

Tags: visual-studio-2010, installation, iis-7.5, iis-6, compatibility

I have received a old compiled source code of a website(was running fine on IIS6) using which I need to create a 64 bit installer for Windows 2008, 2012, Windows 7 64 bit machine etc. I chose Visual Studio 2010 and created an Installer package. Now I am getting below issue at very first stage:

"The installer was interrupted before application could be installed. You need to restart the installer to try again"

It is an IIS compatibility issue and can be resolved easily when selected "IIS Metabase and IIS 6 Configuration compatibility option" in IIS settings.

This site works perfect when configured manually.

It seems, installer goes to check IIS compatibility and to use installer, it becomes necessary to go and check "IIS6 metabase and IIS6 Configuration compatibility" in IIS settings.

Now my question is : I don't want to do changes in IIS but want to remove installer's dependency on checking IIS. Do we have any such setting in installer itself using which it won't go and check IIS compatibility and will not interrupt installation.

Comment: I came to know by a blog, that this installer still points old IIS(i.e. IIS6). It would be great if some has remedy on it.

Comment: In addition to that I was looking for Inno setup and InstallShield LE in vs2012 but it seems it is all good for desktop application, it does not shows any information about IIS setup during installation and expects programs .exe